# Python using zenity with var

Tags: python, subprocess, zenity

I'm trying to run Zenity in a python script, to display a variable.

```
nmaj = 10
cmd = ["zenity" "--question" "--text='Are you " + str(nmaj) + "years old ?'"]
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Can I put a string in the command? How?
Thanks

Comment: Is that supposed to be one long string, or a list of strings. If the former you need to use `+` to append each string. If the latter, you need to use `,` to separate each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `format` and putting `''` outer than `""`:

```
nmaj = 10
cmd = 'zenity --question --text="Are you {} years old ?"'.format(nmaj)
subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: As [@falsetru demonstrates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22862944/4279): no need to use `shell=True`. Use `{:d}` to assert that `nmaj` is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You miss comma(`,`)s between command line arguments:

```
cmd = ["zenity", "--question", "--text='Are you " + str(nmaj) + "years old ?'"]
```

Otherwise the string literals are concatenated into a string (See [String literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)):

```
>>> "zenity" "--question" "--text='Are you "
"zenity--question--text='Are you "
```

Comment: `--text` and its value could be passed as separated arguments: `[..., "--text", "Are you {n:d} years old?".format(n=nmaj)]`